# alternative to CRT function in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a VC++ old application written for Windows NT where `_outp` CRT functions have been used.
Now I have moved this application to VS2015 VC++ platform. So I get an error as identifier `_outp` not being defined in VS2015 compiler.

What is the alternative to `_outp` function in VC++ 2015? I a'm using Windows 10 64 bit system.

Comment: My suggestion is to figure out what the program was trying to do, and do a rewrite.  There is no one-to-one equivalent to those old functions.

Comment: If you're migrating anyhow... why use VS *2015*?

Comment: Note that a rewrite may not be trivial.  If that old app was attempting to talk to some hardware, then you may need to write a device driver.

Comment: https://github.com/ellysh/InpOut32